# Xpath for extracting links

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I create an scraper for an automoto site and first I want to get all manufactures and after that all links of models for each manufactures but with the code below I get only the first model on the list. Why?

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.auto-types.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query("//li[@class='clearfix_center']/a/@href");
$output = array();
foreach($entries as $e) {  
  $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom2->loadHTMLFile('http://www.auto-types.com' . $e->textContent);
  $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2);
  $data = array();
  $data['newLinks'] = trim($xpath2->query("//div[@class='modelImage']/a/@href")->item(0)->textContent);

  $output[] = $data;
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($output, true) . '</pre>';

?>
```

SO I need to get: mercedes/100, mercedes/200, mercedes/300 but now with my script i get only the first link so mercedes/100...

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the results instead of just taking the first item:

```
$items = $xpath2->query("//div[@class='modelImage']/a/@href");
$links = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    $links[] = $item->textContent;
}
$data['newLinks'] = implode(', ', $links);
```